# I want to host the same website content on different domains

Tags: multiple-domains

I need to find out how I can host different domains which will have the same content. I want users to be able to choose their country and based on that decide which domain to load. How do I do this without having to duplicate content? thanks

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about why you want do do that. It's bad for SEO as @vinoth points out, and does not seem to be reasonable to me either. Or, would you provide translated content on your different domains?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to:

- register the international domains;
- point them to your provider;
- setup your provider nameservers to server all that domains;
- use HTTP_HOST environment variable in your code to detect from which domain the user is accessing, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Your making your content spam by your own work. Now google looking on big eye about duplicate content. Recently they have changed their algorithm which includes panda

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called Duplicate Content and it's generally bad for SEO, but in some cases this is unavoidable.

To circumvent the duplicate content issue for same language content in different countries, you could set the `hreflang` with `rel="alternate"` attributes to tell the search engines which language content belongs where:

Scenario:

Website A offers content for France, incl. French content and English content.
Website B offers content for Swiss, incl. French content and English content.

Now, both websites have the exact same content offered, just for different markets. With the hreflang and rel=alternate you could tell Google that Website A should be offered only in `language_Country` `fr_FR` and Website B `fr_CH`.

More information [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=189077) and [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean here.

Are you wanting identical content on different TLD's that are specific to countries? ie .co.uk for UK, .com for US, .ie for Italy

Or are you wanting one domain/TLD and to serve up different content based on the users country of origin?

If so you can use a variety of different Geolocation techniques. [IP2Location](http://www.ip2location.com/) is one company that offers a fairly robust solution.

Comment: I want your first option quote:"Are you wanting identical content on different TLD's that are specific to countries? ie .co.uk for UK, .com for US, .ie for Italy". thanks Digital Essence

Answer (score 0):

you can make one code which detects from where the person is coming.
and then redirect according to the location to that domain.
and all the domains should be pointed to the same server where you host your files.

so suppose the person comes to yoursite.com and he's coming from UK, then your code should redirect him to yoursite.co.uk's homepage. you'll need IP detection to check the place from where the person is visiting.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure all the domains are pointing to the same server. Then set up a Virtual Host for each domain pointing to the same directory on the server, where your site content is located. If all other settings will be the same for all the domains you can define them all as part of the same Virtual Host entry in your web servers configuration.

If you are using Cpanel or something similar, just make sure each domain is pointing to the same directory.

Alternatively, you could do this by modifying your name servers with CNAMEs.