# Search engines, different vhosts on same server, with some stuff in common: do I risk blacklisting?

Tags: seo, blacklist

I don't want to have different domain names that point to the same server, of stuff [like this here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11394/i-want-o-host-the-same-website-content-on-different-domains).

My problem is a bit different.

Let's take the real example, then we can generalize the problem.

I'm "Olivier Pons". I have my own blog here at http://olivierpons.fr, server: 88.191.136.228.

I have a another website that is about to open, that has *nothing to do with my blog*. It's a Website where you can put your jobs. It will have the same server, i.e. 88.191.136.228.

I will be the first to be registered, with my job, and my name will appear in 78 different pages (78 departments actually).

I there any chance (is it a chance?) some SEOs will blacklist me?

### To generalize:

If we host different websites on the same server **and** if they have some things in common, what are the chances to be blacklisted?

Comment: FYI, search engines are not called, "SEOs". They are "search engines". That's a really important thing to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shared hosting is very common today, especially with the current IP address shortage. Search engines know this and will only institute a ban when it's clear a host itself, not just a single domain, is compromised or engaging in questionable activities at an organized scale.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, a server will only be blacklisted if it is doing some nasty Blackhat SEO, which involves many obscure things.

Big hosting companies host up to 50 websites on a single IP, so your fear is unnecessary.

Might i ask why your website in the first place will link to your blog at 78 pages? That seems like horrible design out of the box.

Comment: Write me at olivier dot pons at gmail if you want more details.

Comment: Well it won't link to my blog at all, but there will be my CV on the site, where you'll read "Olivier Pons" on 78 different pages

Answer (score 1):

Search engines aren't stupid. Except on very rare occasions (which are usually fixed soon after), they always think through and test any algorithm changes carefully. The situation you described is not a corner case or even a minority case. That's a situation that occurs on most web hosts and websites. So naturally Google/Bing/Yahoo aren't going to penalize you just for that.

If it doesn't make sense (ie. doesn't improve search results for the user) to penalize websites for sharing IP addresses or treat shared hosting sites differently from sites on dedicated servers, then the search engines aren't going to do it. Why would they?

Likewise, duplicate content penalties are to prevent search results from containing redundant pages (which is completely useless to users) and to discourage spammers and like-minded webmasters from generating large volumes of pages to flood the search index.

It's perfectly natural for a site to have keywords which show up on multiple pages. If your site is about Rottweilers, then of course "Rottweiler" is going to show up a bunch of times on different pages all over your website. So why would Google or Bing punish a webmaster for that sort of repetition? The people who work at Google/Bing/etc. are smart enough to look at how much content two pages have in common before labeling them as duplicates. Just because they have 5-6 words in common out of 200-300 words doesn't mean they're duplicate content. Likewise, they know to take shared navigation menus and header and footer content into account.

The only thing you need to be concerned with is whether the design of your site is useful to the end user. Is the repetition of your name on 78 pages good design (ie. does it add value for the user?), or is it just needless repetition from poor site architecture?